# Is there a catalogue of collection related design patterns in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, memory-management, vector

Since the broader usage of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` to handle memory management came up, I often run into problems of their proper usage in collections like `std::vector`. I'm looking for a catalogue of design patterns oder common usages - especially for C++ due to the issue of memory management.

I give an example of what I'm looking for:

If you want to store a collection of objects of some class `A` in a `std::vector` or other collection (I drop the `std` from now on). Furthermore you want to have the owner of the `vector` have ownership of all the objects. Then there are at least two safe options for that:

1. Use `vector<A>`
2. Use `vector<unique_ptr<A>>`
3. Use `vector<shared_ptr<A>>`
4. Use `vector<A*>`

All have advantages and disadvantages like for 1) A has to be assignable and references to objects change if the vector changes.

For 2) I don't want to give `unique_ptr<A>` objects to the user unless I really do want to hand the object over to them.

And there are some related questions like: How do I give users of the class storing the `vector` the entire collection or the ability to iterate over the objects?

etc....

So is there some reference where I can find this and similar questions analyzed in some detail?

Comment: You should ask questions about concrete examples, not about generic books / tutorials / other resources.

Comment: There are as many references as use cases. As Dutow suggested, you should point concrete example(s)

Comment: So sad. Both +1 and voted to close as too broad.

Comment: I guess this would be a good topic for the new [stackoverflow documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/topics)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback anyway! I will keep my eyes open upon the new SO documentation and ask a more specific question if it comes up.

Comment: I could extract a valid question from the above.  Like "I want to store some data in a random-access container.  When adding elements, I don't want to invalidate references or iterators to those elements, and I want be able to access them by index.  A `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` seems ideal, but how do I permit users to iterate over the collection of `A`s without exposing the `unique_ptr`: I don't want to expose a `unique_ptr` when I don't intend for the end user to be allowed to destroy the object".  Or somesuch.